# KnexJS - multiple `with` clauses with union all

Tags: javascript, postgresql, knex.js

I am trying to achieve something like this with KnexJS:

```
WITH first AS (SELECT ...etc...),
second AS (SELECT ...etc... WHERE NOT EXISTS (TABLE first))
SELECT * FROM first
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM second
```

Can it be done with KnexJS?
Knex provides a `.with` method but I see no information about how I can achieve multiple `WITH` as in the statement above. Likewise there is a `.unionAll` method, but how to mix it with `.with` is not clear.

The exact statement I am after (for postgresql) is:

```sql
WITH first AS (
SELECT results.simulation_id, simulation_time, variable, value, runset_id, (case WHEN ended_at is null then 'INCOMPLETE' else 'COMPLETE' END) as status FROM results
JOIN bookkeeping as bk ON bk.simulation_id = results.simulation_id
WHERE bk.simulation_id=?
AND variable=?
ORDER BY simulation_time
),
second AS (
 SELECT simulation_id, null::real as simulation_time, null as variable, null::real as value, null as runset_id, (case WHEN ended_at is null then 'INCOMPLETE' else 'COMPLETE' END) as status FROM bookkeeping
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (TABLE first)
 AND simulation_id=?
)
SELECT * FROM first
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM second;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add multiple `.with` statements and `knex` will sort it out for you.

I believe your query would end up looking this like this:

```js
const query = knex
    .with(
      'first',
      knex('results')
        .select(
          'results.simulation_id',
          'simulation_time',
          'variable',
          'value',
          'runset_id',
          knex.raw(`(case WHEN ended_at is null then 'INCOMPLETE' else 'COMPLETE' END) as status`),
        )
        .join('bookkeeping as bk', 'bk.simulation_id', 'results.simulation_id')
        .where('bk.simulation_id', 1)
        .andWhere('variable', INSERT_VARIABLE_HERE)
        .orderBy('simulation_time'),
    )
    .with(
      'second',
      knex('bookkeeping')
        .select(
          'simulation_id',
          db.raw('null::real as simulation_time'),
          db.raw('null as variable'),
          db.raw('null::real as value'),
          db.raw('null as runset_id'),
          db.raw(`(case WHEN ended_at is null then 'INCOMPLETE' else 'COMPLETE' END) as status`),
        )
        .whereNotExists(knex('first'))
        .andWhere('simulation_id', INSERT_VARIABLE_HERE),
    )
    .select('*')
    .from('first')
    .unionAll([knex('second').select('*')]);
};
```